# Need to plot histogram in Pandas such that x axis is categorical and y axis is sum of some column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-processing

I have a data frame in Pandas (using Python 3.7) as shown below:

```
#     actuals  probability   bucket
# 0      0.0     0.116375      2
# 1      0.0     0.239069      3   
# 2      1.0     0.591988      6
# 3      0.0     0.273709      3
# 4      1.0     0.929855      10
```

Where 'bucket' can take discreet values from 1 to 10. And 'actuals' can take only 2 values, either 1 or 0.
I need to plot a histogram such that x-axis = 'bucket' (i.e 1 to 10) and y-axis = Sum of 'actuals' . Then how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) with [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.groupby('bucket')['actuals'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
```

If need `histogram` use `kind='hist'`

Comment: Hi @sandeep , kind='bar' solution worked. In addition to this, I have tried below code snippet and it also worked.

**bin_data_df_sorted.groupby('bucket').actuals.sum().plot(kind='bar')**

Can you break this line down and let me know why "actuals.sum()" is working fine and what does it mean? (I am new to Python)

Comment: @Bhuvi007 You can access dataframe columns using `.column_name`, That is why you are able to access using `.actuals`. But this fails if you have special characters like `.` in the column name or like spaces.